# Difference between Service Fabric SDK vs. RunTime

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between `Microsoft Azure Service Fabric` (runtime) vs. `Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK` ?

I have different versions of both installed and want to ensure they are compatible  since `Actor` service is giving issues with reminder callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runtime are the binaries and libraries used to run the cluster, the actual Service Fabric.

SDK are the libraries and tools used to program applications targeting the Runtime.

Their versions are different, but follow a similar versioning. In example, the most recent [release](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2019/02/04/azure-service-fabric-6-4-refresh-release/), was released:

- Runtime 6.4.622
- .Net SDK 3.3.622 with SF SDK 6.4.622
- Java SDK - 1.0.1

In summary,

newer SDK  does not work well on older Runtime, but old SDK works well with newer runtime, because newer runtimes generally add new features and keep the old ones, but not the other way round.